# Wix - conditionally install a file to C:\MyConfig folder

Tags: file, wix, windows-installer, installation

I want to install a configuration file from my Wix setup project to C: drive, MyConfig folder. 
I have a hard time to specify C:\ in directory, as the character ":" is not permitted in the attribute "Name".

Also I would like the file to be installed conditionally, and in such a way that is NOT removed during uninstall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and error I found the answer. I just need to simply add SetDirectory element that will override my C Drive directory, like that.

```
<PropertyRef Id="ENV_DEPLOY"/>
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="CompanyName" Name="!(bind.property.Manufacturer)">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="!(bind.property.ProductName)" />
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
    <Directory Id="CDrive" Name="CDrive">
        <Directory Id="ConfigDir" Name="MyConfig" />
    </Directory>
</Directory>

<SetDirectory Id="CDrive" Value="C:\" />

<ComponentGroup Id="EnvironmentSetup" Directory="ConfigDir"  >
    <Component Id="currentEnvironment_DEVELOPMENT" Guid="*" Permanent="yes" >
        <Condition>ENV_DEPLOY="DEVELOPMENT"</Condition>
        <File Id="ConfigFile_DEVELOPMENT" Source="DEVELOPMENT\currentEnvironment.config" />
    </Component>
    <Component Id="currentEnvironment_PRODUCTION" Guid="*" Permanent="yes" >
        <Condition>ENV_DEPLOY="PRODUCTION"</Condition>
        <File Id="ConfigFile_PRODUCTION" Source="PRODUCTION\currentEnvironment.config" />
    </Component>
</ComponentGroup>
```

Comment: I say it again, **C:\Config is a system folder**. It is an internal implementation detail for Windows Installer and should never be used for your own deployment at all. In fact diligent system administrators are aware of what this folder is for, and know it can sometimes be "stuck" on systems full of obsolete rollback files after failed installs - they might make scripts to clean out the whole folder and your whole application will be zapped along with it. In addition Windows itself may perform unpredictable actions on the folder without warning. Is it so hard to just deploy somewhere else?

Comment: I changed Config to MyConfig

Comment: Much better - thanks for listening, but if you can change that folder you can also install to [ProgramFilesFolder] instead, which would mean you no longer fight the Windows Installer design. Is the folder read-only after installation, or do you change the files in there?

Comment: **Errors in this design**: **1)** the setup will bomb out if the system drive is different from "C:\". **2)** binding directory names to variables is not a great idea - upgrade and patching problems may result. **3)** the setup does not install to a folder under program files. **4)** the setup targets a core Windows system folder for installation (later changed). **5)** targeting the same file for installation in different incarnation isn't ideal (use WiX's XML update feature instead). Out of space to comment more - please don't use these designs. Problems are certain. Follow basic rules.

Comment: C:\Config is a system folder. I don't have that folder on my PC, how do I access it?

Answer (score -1):

I know you just want an answer, but please consider other solution options. This construct fights the Windows Installer design, and I can guarantee you it will fight back. This fight is not worth it. All of Windows Installer is designed to not allow such unusual (and unnecessary) deployment constructs. There must be alternatives.

Why do you want to access the **C:\Config folder**? We really need to know to understand what you want to achieve. This is an **internal system folder** for the Windows Installer engine. It generally stores **rollback files** for any running MSI installs. **I can't think of a single reason to do anything in this folder at all** - it is just not safe.

Comment: C:\Config is the folder internal applications use. If you know how to deploy to it, please provide the solution.

Comment: What kind of internal applications would do that? What functions do they perform? We really must know in order to make sense of this. Windows Installer "actively resists" deploying to folders such as this - it really is not possible to provide sound advice for how to do it, but we may help determine if there is a better way to achieve what you want. Give us some more information and I am sure we will find a way.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul He just picked a poor name for an example folder. I don't think he's accessing any "internal system folder", at least not intentionally. He simply wanted to know how to set the directory name since a : was not allowed in the name attribute. Is his posted solution using SetDirectory the proper way?

Comment: No, overriding directories this way is not safe and not recommended - side effects are almost certain. And the folder in question is a core MSI folder that should never be accessed or written to at all. The "solution" above should actually be removed before other people try to do the same thing. We are Windows Installer specialists - why do people not listen when we warn them about erroneous designs? The reason it is hard to install directly to C:\ is because nothing should ever be installed there in the first place.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul Where Do I find the installed *files/folder* by MSI package? Have developed WPF application and created MSI using WiX with default settings, So I need to find out the folder or files that have been installed by MSI package.